# How to return more than one value to jQuery.Ajax success function

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to return more than one value to jqueryAjax success but failed to do so. this what I have done so far......

```
 String emp = request.getParameter("ID");
    ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList();
    al=ur.editLeave(emp);
    String cl = al.get(0);
    out.print(cl);
    out.print(al.get(1));
    out.print(al.get(2));
```

from this jsp page I try to return 3 values.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    data: 'ID=' + idel,
    async: false,
    url: "ForleaveMaster.jsp?Eleave=l",
    success: function(cl, ml, ot) {
        alert(cl, ml, ot);
        $('input[id=ELM_CL]').val($.trim(cl));
        $('input[id=ELM_ML]').val($.trim(cl));
        $('input[id=ELM_OT]').val($.trim(cl));
    },
    error: function() {}
});
```

Please help me out.

Comment: you could merge the data with some delimiter and parse it in ajax response, or send it as json and parse json in your ajax response..!

Comment: you are setting the input fields all to the same value  $('input[id=ELM_OT]').val($.trim(cl)); All are going to be cl.

Comment: You can only have 1 parameter for your success function: if you need more than 1 value then wrap these values in a server-side object that you stringify with JSON so that you're returning 1 string that you parse back to an object on the client, and from which you can retrieve the different values you need.

Comment: wil you please elaborate me this, that how to wrap values

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Everything you return is passed as a first argument to your function.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    data: 'ID=' + idel,
    async: false,
    url: "ForleaveMaster.jsp?Eleave=l",
    success: function(data) {
        var array_data = String(data).split("\n");
        var cl = array_data[0],
            mt = array_data[1],
            ot = array_data[2];
        alert(cl,ml,ot);
        $('input[id=ELM_CL]').val($.trim(cl));
        $('input[id=ELM_ML]').val($.trim(cl));
        $('input[id=ELM_OT]').val($.trim(cl));
    },
    error: function() {                        
    }
});
```

Comment: I'm intrigued by the `data.spit()` method!

Comment: does i have to download any plugin to use data.split function. because while using this i got an error: data.spit is not a function

Comment: Let's continue in [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33062/mishik-subodh)

Answer (score 2):

Your approach definitely won't work: you can only return one 'item'. The trick is to put all your values in that item. Encode your response as a JSON string (sorry - can't help with that in JSP) but it should look like a bit like this:

{"cl":"1", "dl":"2", "cl":"3"}

Then modify your AJAX function:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        data: 'ID=' + idel,
        dataType:'json'
        async: false,
        url: "ForleaveMaster.jsp?Eleave=l",
        success: function(data) {
            alert(data.cl,data.ml,data.ot);
            $('input[id=ELM_CL]').val($.trim(data.cl));
            $('input[id=ELM_ML]').val($.trim(data.ml));
            $('input[id=ELM_OT]').val($.trim(data.ot));
        },
        error: function() {                        
        }
    });
```

I'd leave `async` set to `true` or your browser will freeze while the server responds. Using Json has the advantage that you can add additional data or change the order without breaking your Javascript.

Comment: thnks but m still struggling to get over this.

Answer (score 1):

As we all already know, the best way to help somebody in programming is to show them example. So here is my part of it.

**PHP FILE and response**

```
<?php

require_once('../../../wp-load.php');

$cs_confID = $_POST['cs_confID'];

$cs_date = $_POST['cs_date'];

$cs_obj = get_conf_id_for_insert($cs_date, $cs_confID);

$json_cs = array();    

if(count($cs_obj) == 1)    
{
    $json_cs = array('cs_id'=>$cs_obj[0]->cs_id,'cs_date'=>$cs_obj[0]->cs_date); //Make array of files    
    echo json_encode($json_cs); //Encode json    
}    

else    
{    
    echo '<p style="color:red">Status:Error. Please contact our support for further help!</p>';    
}
?>
```

**HTML and Jquery**

```
$.ajax({ url: '../wp-content/themes/rirads-2012-child-theme/insert_conference_schedules.php',

data: {cs_date:$("#c_date").val(),cs_confID: $("#conf").val()},
beforeSend: function(){ $("#loaderAjax").show(); },
type: 'post',
success: function(output) 
{
$("#loaderAjax").hide();
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(output); //decode JSON response

$("#cs_id").val(obj.cs_id); //Fill the value of current cs_id into input field cs_id

$("#cs_date").val(obj.cs_date); //Fill the value of current cs_date into input field cs_date

//code goes on...
```

Hope it will help you.. :)

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you want to set the values as form inputs? In that case replace your success with:

```
 success: function(cl,ml,ot) { alert(cl,ml,ot);
       $('input[id=ELM_CL]').val($.trim(cl));
       $('input[id=ELM_ML]').val($.trim(ml));
       $('input[id=ELM_OT]').val($.trim(ot));
  },
```

You were setting all the fields to the same cl value.